# Sublime Text requires restart on settings changes to take effect

Tags: settings, sublimetext, application-restart

My Sublime Text 3 ( but also applies to ST2 as I experienced the same issue before I switched to ST3 ) requires restart for any settings changes to take effect. This happens on a Mac Mini in the office but not on my Macbook Pro ( which is pretty much the same setup ).

I do sync settings over Dropbox by symlinking `Application Support/Sublime Text 3` folder to Dropbox. However, I can recall it happening even before I did that.

Any ideas how to make it apply settings changes immediately?

Comment: Update: I've never been able to resolve this issue. It might have been something very specific to my system. What has fixed that for me was a clean-install of Yosemite.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you're running the [latest build](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev) of ST3. Remember, this is beta software, and things break/change/get fixed again from version to version, so it may just be an issue with your particular build.

I suspect that this has something to do with Dropbox, as settings changes should be applied as soon as you save the settings file in almost all cases. For example, changing the theme should happen immediately. To test if it's Dropbox-related, unlink your current symlink to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3` and make it a regular directory, then copy all your settings over and try to change something. If it applies right away, then it's an issue with Dropbox.

Comment: Running latest ST3 and I have currently checked my home setup - everything works fine and it's identically symlinked. I'll try static directory and relinking it tomorrow in the office. Tbh, I thought it would be way more popular issue, there must be something with my setup. I'll let know what worked for me.

Comment: Ok, I've checked and there is an issue with Dropbox symlinking. If I use local folders then ST3 refreshes on changes. If I symlink to Dropbox then it stops working. I tried reinstalling Sublime Text, Dropbox, relinking, relinking only Packages and Installed Packages folders, linking with sudo, changing permissions, groups, installing latest python. ST3's console basically says it writes to the file but does not reload it. It basically stops there and does nothing. Still trying to figure it out. And it still does not work. MattDMo thanks for help anyway.

Comment: no problem. If you found my answer helpful, please remember to click the check mark to accept it - it flags the question as being resolved, and we both get reputation points. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package called 'Restart' and then just restart from the admin tab.
Check the package to restart sublime text. It is just perfect https://github.com/yedderson/SublimeRestart

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac:

1. "Cmd + Shift + P"
2. Enter: "Install Packages"
3. Enter: "Restart"
4. Now, you should see the "Restart" option under "File" in me main menu.