# Sublime text 3 settings doesn't reloads until restarting it

Tags: sublimetext3, settings, application-restart

Sublime text 3 doesn't refreshes the folder tree or the reflects the output file changes or reflects the changes in the settings immidiately. I have c++ build system setup on sublime which takes input from "inputf.in" and provides output to "outputf.in", with 3 columns (1 for code + 1 for "inputf.in" + 1 for "outputf.in"). Earlier, all the process used to happen smoothly. On pressing, ctrl + B, it used to display output in "outputf.in", but now the output doesn't changes in the files "outputf.in" until I click on it. My program runs on pressing Ctrl + B but the output doesn't changes in the file until I click on it. Also, for some reason when this happens, the folder tree refuses to work too. It doesn't shows the files I have newly created in the folder.

After, rebooting the system, this seems to go away. But after a reboot and then closing and reopening the application again results in the problem I stated above. This is really annoying and this didn't use to happen before. I don't know what suddenly happened. Also, I have noticed that no changes are reflected at all in sublime. Not a single one. I created a new build system file and the new build system didn't show up in the sublime until restarted sublime text 3. Similarly, none of the settings reloads until I completely restart sublime text 3.

I also read answers of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852901/sublime-text-requires-restart-on-settings-changes-to-take-effect), but it doesn't help me in away.

This started happening all of a sudden. This wasn't happening a day before. It just started happening and I have no idea about it.

I am using Arch Linux if it's helpful somehow. Can it be because of some updates I did after which ST3 stopped working? Here's my pacman log.

```html
[2017-12-16 18:40] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2017-12-16 18:40] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2017-12-16 18:40] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded archlinux-keyring (20171130-1 -> 20171213-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Appending keys from archlinux.gpg...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key DDB867B92AA789C165EEFA799B729B06A680C281...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 684148BB25B49E986A4944C55184252D824B18E8...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 91FFE0700E80619CEB73235CA88E23E377514E00...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key AB19265E5D7D20687D303246BA1DFB64FFF979E7...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Locally signing key 0E8B644079F599DFC1DDC3973348882F6AC6A4C2...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Importing owner trust values...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Disabling revoked keys in keyring...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 7FA647CD89891DEDC060287BB9113D1ED21E1A55...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key D4DE5ABDE2A7287644EAC7E36D1A9E70E19DAA50...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 40440DC037C05620984379A6761FAD69BA06C6A9...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key B1F2C889CB2CCB2ADA36D963097D629E437520BD...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key BC1FBE4D2826A0B51E47ED62E2539214C6C11350...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 63F395DE2D6398BBE458F281F2DBB4931985A992...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 8F76BEEA0289F9E1D3E229C05F946DED983D4366...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 4FCF887689C41B09506BE8D5F3E1D5C5D30DB0AD...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 81D7F8241DB38BC759C80FCE3A726C6170E80477...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5E7585ADFF106BFFBBA319DC654B877A0864983E...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key E7210A59715F6940CF9A4E36A001876699AD6E84...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key F5A361A3A13554B85E57DDDAAF7EF7873CFD4BB6...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 8CF934E339CAD8ABF342E822E711306E3C4F88BC...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 5696C003B0854206450C8E5BE613C09CB4440678...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 9515D8A8EAB88E49BB65EDBCE6B456CAF15447D5...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 4A8B17E20B88ACA61860009B5CED81B7C2E5C0D2...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 0B20CA1931F5DA3A70D0F8D2EA6836E1AB441196...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 34C5D94FE7E7913E86DC427E7FB1A3800C84C0A5...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 39F880E50E49A4D11341E8F939E4F17F295AFBF4...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 66BD74A036D522F51DD70A3C7F2A16726521E06D...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 44D4A033AC140143927397D47EFD567D4C7EA887...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Disabling key 27FFC4769E19F096D41D9265A04F9397CDFD6BB0...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Updating trust database...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-06-25
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded avahi (0.7-1 -> 0.7-2)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded libunistring (0.9.7-1 -> 0.9.8-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded cmake (3.10.0-3 -> 3.10.1-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded hspell (1.3-1 -> 1.4-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded enchant (2.1.2-2 -> 2.1.2-3)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded mesa (17.2.6-1 -> 17.3.0-2)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded librsvg (2:2.40.19-1 -> 2:2.40.20-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded polkit (0.113+29+g3272a98-1 -> 0.113+34+g29ba7af-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded evolution-data-server (3.26.2.1-3 -> 3.26.3-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded evolution (3.26.2-2 -> 3.26.3-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-mesa (17.2.6-1 -> 17.3.0-2)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded logrotate (3.12.3-1 -> 3.13.0-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded openssl-1.0 (1.0.2.l-1 -> 1.0.2.n-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded run-parts (4.8.1-1 -> 4.8.3-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] upgraded upower (0.99.6-1 -> 0.99.7-1)
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'glib-compile-schemas.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'systemd-sysusers.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'texinfo-install.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
[2017-12-16 18:41] [ALPM] running 'update-mime-database.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2017-12-17 03:58] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2017-12-17 03:58] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded btrfs-progs (4.14-1 -> 4.14-2)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded lcms2 (2.8-2 -> 2.9-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded icu (60.1-1 -> 60.2-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded colord (1.4.1-1 -> 1.4.1+6+gf08c25d-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded libinput (1.9.3-1 -> 1.9.4-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded ostree (2017.13-1 -> 2017.14-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] upgraded python-jedi (0.11.0-2 -> 0.11.1-1)
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running '90-linux.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'default'
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.14.5-1-ARCH
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'fallback'
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img -S autodetect
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.14.5-1-ARCH
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running 'glib-compile-schemas.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running 'systemd-hwdb.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running 'systemd-sysusers.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running 'systemd-tmpfiles.hook'...
[2017-12-17 03:58] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:19] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -R sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] removed sublime-text (3143-1)
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:19] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:21] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2017-12-17 04:21] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2017-12-17 04:21] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] upgraded libxkbcommon (0.7.2-1 -> 0.8.0-1)
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] upgraded flatpak (0.10.1-1 -> 0.10.2-1)
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] upgraded libxkbcommon-x11 (0.7.2-1 -> 0.8.0-1)
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:21] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:22] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] installed sublime-text (2.0.2-4)
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:22] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:26] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -R sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] removed sublime-text (2.0.2-4)
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:26] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:27] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:27] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2017-12-17 04:27] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2017-12-17 04:27] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2017-12-17 04:27] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:28] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2017-12-17 04:28] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2017-12-17 04:28] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2017-12-17 04:28] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S sublime-text'
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] installed sublime-text (3143-1)
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] running 'gtk-update-icon-cache.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:28] [ALPM] running 'update-desktop-database.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:49] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S vim'
[2017-12-17 04:49] [ALPM] transaction started
[2017-12-17 04:49] [ALPM] installed vim-runtime (8.0.1389-1)
[2017-12-17 04:49] [ALPM] installed vim (8.0.1389-1)
[2017-12-17 04:49] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2017-12-17 04:49] [ALPM] running 'systemd-update.hook'...
[2017-12-17 04:53] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S gvim'
[2017-12-17 05:59] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -R python'
```

I would love if someone could help me, because this is really annoying and it's hampering my productivity in a big way. I have setup my sublime this way.
Please, I'd really appreciate some help.
[Image of the way I've setup my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8CZl.png)

Comment: Assuming you've checked and you don't have anything in your configuration or package folder symlinked to an external location, is the location of `~/.config/sublime-text-3` on a local hard drive or on a network share of some sort?

Comment: I think I may have discovered the issue. It was because of inotify max_user_watcher. I added `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=10000` to a config file and now everything works. It turned out that none of the applications in my arch was reloading the settings previously (i.e. before adding the inotify line) without restarting the application. After adding the above fix, everything seems to work out I guess. But I have no idea what the above line does and what was the issue in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in my arch linux only. Not only Sublime, but other applications weren't working as expected too. This was mainly due to `inotify` instances. So what I did to fix it was, I added `fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 10000` to the file `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`. `inotify` is used to detect changes in files and directories. Since, by default there weren't enough watches in my arch linux. And therefore, settings weren't reloading properly. The above line increases the number of `inotify` watches.